# Is there a table or catalog of aesthetics for ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to ggplot2 and have been trying to find a comprehensive list of aesthetics.  I think I understand their purpose but it is hard to know which can be used in various situations (mostly geoms?). Hadley's website occasionally lists available aesthetics on pages for individual geoms and the R doc's occasionally (though more rarely) do the same. I even found a geom for which the two do not quite match.

I searched through the comments here for an answer and even bought the book! Alas, no help.

I think it would be fantastic to have a table with all the aesthetics listed in one dimension and all the geoms (and other objects?) listed in another.

Does anyone know of such a thing?

Is there a simple way (command) in R to list all the aesthetics that can be applied to an object?

Here's how a table might start:

```
List           x       y       fill      size    colour   linetype . . .
geom_point    Yes     Yes      Yes       Yes      Yes        No
geom_abline   Yes     Yes      No        Yes      Yes       Yes
.
.
.
```

A catalog of aesthetic definitions/parameters would be a very helpful reference as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer details all aesthetics, not only the default ones.

### Get all Geom* function

```r
library(tidyverse)
env <- asNamespace("ggplot2")
all_Geoms <- ls(envir = env, pattern = "^Geom.+")
all_Geoms <- mget(all_Geoms, env)
```

### Get all aesthetics

```
all_aes <- map(all_Geoms, ~.$aesthetics())

# change Geom* to geom_*
names(all_aes) <- 
  names(all_aes) %>%
  substr(5,nchar(.)) %>% 
  tolower() %>% 
  paste0("geom_",.)

# remove if geom_* doesn't exist
all_aes[!names(all_aes) %in% ls(envir = env)] <- NULL
head(all_aes, 3)
#> $geom_abline
#> [1] "slope"     "intercept" "colour"    "size"      "linetype"  "alpha"    
#> [7] "group"    
#> 
#> $geom_area
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype"
#> [7] "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $geom_bar
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype"
#> [7] "alpha"    "group"
```

### lay out in a long table

```
all_aes_long <- all_aes %>%
  enframe("fun","aes") %>%
  unchop(aes)

all_aes_long
#> # A tibble: 325 x 2
#>    fun         aes      
#>    <chr>       <chr>    
#>  1 geom_abline slope    
#>  2 geom_abline intercept
#>  3 geom_abline colour   
#>  4 geom_abline size     
#>  5 geom_abline linetype 
#>  6 geom_abline alpha    
#>  7 geom_abline group    
#>  8 geom_area   x        
#>  9 geom_area   y        
#> 10 geom_area   colour   
#> # ... with 315 more rows
```

### lay out in a wide table

I suggest to use `View()` to visualize this one.

```
all_aes_wide <-
  all_aes_long%>%
  mutate(val = 1) %>%
  spread(aes,val,fill = 0)

all_aes_wide
#> # A tibble: 38 x 38
#>    fun   alpha angle colour family  fill fontface geometry group height
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 geom~     1     0      1      0     0        0        0     1      0
#>  2 geom~     1     0      1      0     1        0        0     1      0
#>  3 geom~     1     0      1      0     1        0        0     1      0
#>  4 geom~     0     0      0      0     0        0        0     1      0
#>  5 geom~     1     0      1      0     1        0        0     1      0
#>  6 geom~     1     0      1      0     1        0        0     1      0
#>  7 geom~     1     0      1      0     0        0        0     1      0
#>  8 geom~     1     0      1      0     1        0        0     1      0
#>  9 geom~     1     0      1      0     0        0        0     1      0
#> 10 geom~     1     0      1      0     1        0        0     1      0
#> # ... with 28 more rows, and 28 more variables: hjust <dbl>,
#> #   intercept <dbl>, label <dbl>, lineheight <dbl>, linetype <dbl>,
#> #   lower <dbl>, map_id <dbl>, middle <dbl>, radius <dbl>, shape <dbl>,
#> #   size <dbl>, slope <dbl>, stroke <dbl>, subgroup <dbl>, upper <dbl>,
#> #   vjust <dbl>, weight <dbl>, width <dbl>, x <dbl>, xend <dbl>,
#> #   xintercept <dbl>, xmax <dbl>, xmin <dbl>, y <dbl>, yend <dbl>,
#> #   yintercept <dbl>, ymax <dbl>, ymin <dbl>
```

### bonus : frequency of aes

```
table(all_aes_long$aes)
#> 
#>      alpha      angle     colour     family       fill   fontface 
#>         37          3         36          2         20          2 
#>   geometry      group     height      hjust  intercept      label 
#>          1         38          2          2          1          2 
#> lineheight   linetype      lower     map_id     middle     radius 
#>          2         33          1          1          1          1 
#>      shape       size      slope     stroke   subgroup      upper 
#>          4         35          1          4          2          1 
#>      vjust     weight      width          x       xend xintercept 
#>          2          6          2         30          2          1 
#>       xmax       xmin          y       yend yintercept       ymax 
#>          2          2         27          2          1          8 
#>       ymin 
#>          8
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. By the way, why isn't geom_histogram there?

Comment: Still amazed this question lives on after 8 years. Up voted both of you. Will consider toggling accept switch at some point. Do either of you know if this approach would have worked in 2012?

Comment: @Frocha geom_histogram uses GeomBar, so my approach isn't completely rigorous, I'll try to fix that. Meanwhile if it occurs with another geom_* function, print the code, see the Geom* function used, and refer to the corresponding geom_* function in the table I proposed.

Comment: @MT I have no idea if it would have worked in 2012, but I know ggplot internals changed a lot at some point

Comment: Changed to accepted answer as suggested by @FRocha

Answer (score 130):

Below is the `default_aes` for each geom,

```
            colour size linetype alpha   fill weight shape width height angle hjust vjust family fontface lineheight
abline       black  0.5        1   yes     --     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
area           yes  0.5        1   yes grey20     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
bar            yes  0.5        1   yes grey20      1    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
bin2d          yes  0.5        1   yes grey60      1    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
boxplot     grey20  0.5    solid   yes  white      1    16    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
contour    #3366FF  0.5        1   yes     --      1    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
crossbar     black  0.5        1   yes    yes     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
density      black  0.5        1   yes    yes      1    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
density2d  #3366FF  0.5        1   yes     --      1    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
errorbar     black  0.5        1   yes     --     --    --   0.5     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
errorbarh    black  0.5        1   yes     --     --    --    --    0.5    --    --    --     --       --         --
freqpoly     black  0.5        1   yes     --     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
hex            yes  0.5       --   yes grey50     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
hline        black  0.5        1   yes     --     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
linerange    black  0.5        1   yes     --     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
path         black  0.5        1   yes     --     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
point        black    2       --   yes    yes     --    16    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
pointrange   black  0.5        1   yes    yes     --    16    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
polygon         NA  0.5        1   yes grey20     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
quantile   #3366FF  0.5        1   yes     --      1    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
raster          --   --       --   yes grey20     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
rect           yes  0.5        1   yes grey20     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
ribbon         yes  0.5        1   yes grey20     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
rug          black  0.5        1   yes     --     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
segment      black  0.5        1   yes     --     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
smooth     #3366FF  0.5        1   0.4 grey60      1    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
step         black  0.5        1   yes     --     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
text         black    5       --   yes     --     --    --    --     --     0   0.5   0.5               1        1.2
tile           yes  0.1        1   yes grey20     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
violin      grey20  0.5    solid   yes  white      1    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
vline        black  0.5        1   yes     --     --    --    --     --    --    --    --     --       --         --
```

and the ugly code I used to hack this,

```
find_aes <- function(geom="point"){

  tryCatch({
  Geom <- getFromNamespace(paste("Geom", ggplot2:::firstUpper(geom), sep=""),
                           "ggplot2")

  tmp <- unclass(Geom$default_aes)
  tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- "yes"
  data.frame(tmp, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }, error = function(e) {})
}

funs <- grep("^geom_", ls("package:ggplot2"),val=T)

geoms <- gsub("^geom_", "", funs)

all <- lapply(geoms, find_aes)
names(all) <- geoms
relevant <- sapply(all, function(x) !is.null(x) && nrow(x) > 0)
library(plyr)
results = do.call("rbind.fill",all)
rownames(results) <- names(relevant[relevant])
results[is.na(results)] <- "--"

options(width=9999)
capture.output(print(results), file="aes.txt")
```

Comment: +1!, in addition, would be it be true that if a geom has a default above that it supports that aes? I think so...

Comment: it's not quite clear to me which of those are real aesthetics that can be mapped with a scale.

Answer (score 12):

Have a look to [Aesthetic specifications](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html)'s vignette, by Hadley Wickham:

*This vignette summarises the various formats that grid drawing functions take. Most of this information is available scattered throughout the R documentation. This appendix brings it all together in one place.*