# What are the default ggplot2 plot margins?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot find information on this anywhere. I know how to set them but want to know the defaults (top, right, bottom, and left) so its less of a guessing game when setting margins for a plot.

Comment: You might like this question, which goes yet a little further: [Is there a table or catalog of aesthetics for ggplot2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657380/is-there-a-table-or-catalog-of-aesthetics-for-ggplot2)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For plot margins as well as other parameters, the default values are that of `theme_grey`:

```
theme_grey()$plot.margin
[1] 5.5pt 5.5pt 5.5pt 5.5pt
```

However, the default theme might change in the future, and you can set a different one (with `theme_set()`) so a more robust way would be to use `theme_get()` which returns the current theme (@r2evans comment)

```
theme_get()$plot.margin
```

Comment: Note that margins are different in different themes. For example: `theme_cowplot()$plot.margin` will produce `7pt 7pt 7pt 7pt`

Comment: Another method (not sure when it became available) is `theme_get()$plot.margin`, which appears to indicate the default theme. It currently returns the same margins as this answer.