# Which aesthetics go in ggplot( ) and which in geom_xx( )

Tags: r, ggplot2

How should I decide when to put parameters in `ggplot( )` or in the `geom_xx( )`? Does it matter if the parameter is set to a constant or to a column from the data frame? What other factors (R pun unintentional) should be considered?

This seems to work fine, but has a legend which lists the transparency.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, col = cyl, alpha = 0.6))+geom_point(size = 4)
```

This is a slight improvement because the legend has been removed, but seems to be the same otherwise.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, col = cyl))+geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.6)
```

I understand that parameters should be defined once when possible if they apply to all `geoms` and separately when they should apply to only one `geom` or if they should override settings from `ggplot`. There's a helpful list of aesthetics here:
[Is there a table or catalog of aesthetics for ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657380/is-there-a-table-or-catalog-of-aesthetics-for-ggplot2) and a nice graphical representation [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/vignettes/ggplot2-specs.html).

Comment: You'll get a legend for each aesthetic inside `aes()`. If the aesthetic is in the call to `ggplot` it will apply to every `geom`. If it's in `geom_xxx()` it will apply only to that `geom`. If you don't want the transparency to show up in the legend, put `alpha=0.6` outside the `aes()`. In most cases, inside `aes()` you'll only want to map an aesthetic to a variable, because the point of the mapping is to have a different `color` or `alpha` or `shape`, etc. for different values of that variable. If you want a constant color, alpha, shape, etc., put it outside the `aes()`.

Comment: I you want to _map_ an aesthetic to a variable, put it within `aes`. Put that `aes` inside `ggplot` to map it for all geoms, put it inside the `geom` to map it only for that geom. If you want to _set_ a variable to a constant, give it as a direct argument to the `geom`.

Comment: Both replies were very helpful, thanks!

Comment: One additional point: sometimes it _is_ helpful to map a constant inside of `aes()` -- when you are making multiple calls to the same `geom_xxx` for different subsets of data. that is not (generally) a great approach if it can be avoided, but it can be quick way to plot two subsets (or columns) particularly if you are trying to do slightly different things with them.