# R ggplot2 aes arguments - How do I know what arguments are valid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am learning R and I was not able to find a comprehensive list of arguments which I can put into the aes() call. The RStudio help just states aes(x, y, ...) but that "...": How do I know what can be put there?

I found by calling `??aes` I can get a good overview of what is possible (see here
https://bookdown.org/yih_huynh/Guide-to-R-Book/basic-aesthetics.html ).

But I also know from a course I can use arguments like "group".
Example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dslabs)
data(heights)
p <- heights %>% 
  ggplot(aes(height, group = sex)) +
  geom_density()
```

So the question is: Is there a full list of arguments which I can use in the aesthetic mappings?

Comment: The whole point of `...` is that you *can't* - in general - know which aes are valid.  The arguments that are valid in a particular call to `aes()` will depend on the geom within which the call is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by @Limey, it depends on the geom you use. In this post ([Is there a table or catalog of aesthetics for ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657380/is-there-a-table-or-catalog-of-aesthetics-for-ggplot2)), @moodymudskipper gave a really nice answer to see the arguments in the aesthetics. Here a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
env <- asNamespace("ggplot2")
all_geoms <- ls(envir = env, pattern = "^Geom.+")
all_geoms <- mget(all_geoms, env)

all_aes <- map(all_geoms, ~.$aesthetics())
all_aes
#> $GeomAbline
#> [1] "slope"     "intercept" "colour"    "size"      "linetype"  "alpha"    
#> [7] "group"    
#> 
#> $GeomAnnotationMap
#> [1] "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "subgroup" "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomArea
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"   
#> [8] "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomBar
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"   
#> [8] "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomBlank
#> [1] "group"
#> 
#> $GeomBoxplot
#>  [1] "x"        "y"        "lower"    "xlower"   "upper"    "xupper"  
#>  [7] "middle"   "xmiddle"  "ymin"     "xmin"     "ymax"     "xmax"    
#> [13] "weight"   "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "alpha"    "shape"   
#> [19] "linetype" "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomCol
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"   
#> [8] "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomContour
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "weight"   "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "alpha"   
#> [8] "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomContourFilled
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"   
#> [8] "subgroup" "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomCrossbar
#>  [1] "x"        "y"        "ymin"     "xmin"     "ymax"     "xmax"    
#>  [7] "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomCurve
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "xend"     "yend"     "colour"   "size"     "linetype"
#> [8] "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomCustomAnn
#> [1] "xmin"  "xmax"  "ymin"  "ymax"  "group"
#> 
#> $GeomDensity
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "fill"     "weight"   "colour"   "alpha"    "size"    
#> [8] "linetype" "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomDensity2d
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomDensity2dFilled
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"   
#> [8] "subgroup" "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomDotplot
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "fill"     "alpha"    "stroke"   "linetype"
#> [8] "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomErrorbar
#>  [1] "x"        "y"        "ymin"     "xmin"     "ymax"     "xmax"    
#>  [7] "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "width"    "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomErrorbarh
#> [1] "xmin"     "xmax"     "y"        "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "height"  
#> [8] "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomFunction
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomHex
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"   
#> [8] "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomHline
#> [1] "yintercept" "colour"     "size"       "linetype"   "alpha"     
#> [6] "group"     
#> 
#> $GeomLabel
#>  [1] "x"          "y"          "label"      "colour"     "fill"      
#>  [6] "size"       "angle"      "hjust"      "vjust"      "alpha"     
#> [11] "family"     "fontface"   "lineheight" "group"     
#> 
#> $GeomLine
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomLinerange
#>  [1] "x"        "y"        "ymin"     "xmin"     "ymax"     "xmax"    
#>  [7] "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomLogticks
#> [1] "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomMap
#> [1] "map_id"   "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "subgroup"
#> [8] "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomPath
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomPoint
#> [1] "x"      "y"      "shape"  "colour" "size"   "fill"   "alpha"  "stroke"
#> [9] "group" 
#> 
#> $GeomPointrange
#>  [1] "x"        "y"        "ymin"     "xmin"     "ymax"     "xmax"    
#>  [7] "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "shape"    "fill"     "alpha"   
#> [13] "stroke"   "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomPolygon
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"   
#> [8] "subgroup" "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomQuantile
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "weight"   "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "alpha"   
#> [8] "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomRaster
#> [1] "x"     "y"     "fill"  "alpha" "group"
#> 
#> $GeomRasterAnn
#> [1] "group"
#> 
#> $GeomRect
#>  [1] "xmin"     "xmax"     "ymin"     "ymax"     "colour"   "fill"    
#>  [7] "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomRibbon
#>  [1] "x"        "y"        "ymin"     "xmin"     "ymax"     "xmax"    
#>  [7] "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomRug
#> [1] "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "x"        "y"        "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomSegment
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "xend"     "yend"     "colour"   "size"     "linetype"
#> [8] "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomSf
#> [1] "geometry" "shape"    "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype" "alpha"   
#> [8] "stroke"   "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomSmooth
#>  [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "linetype"
#>  [7] "weight"   "alpha"    "ymin"     "ymax"     "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomSpoke
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "angle"    "radius"   "colour"   "size"     "linetype"
#> [8] "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomStep
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "colour"   "size"     "linetype" "alpha"    "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomText
#>  [1] "x"          "y"          "label"      "colour"     "size"      
#>  [6] "angle"      "hjust"      "vjust"      "alpha"      "family"    
#> [11] "fontface"   "lineheight" "group"     
#> 
#> $GeomTile
#>  [1] "x"        "y"        "fill"     "colour"   "size"     "linetype"
#>  [7] "alpha"    "width"    "height"   "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomViolin
#> [1] "x"        "y"        "weight"   "colour"   "fill"     "size"     "alpha"   
#> [8] "linetype" "group"   
#> 
#> $GeomVline
#> [1] "xintercept" "colour"     "size"       "linetype"   "alpha"     
#> [6] "group"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As said by @Limey in the comments, there's no comprehensive list in the docs of each `geom_` because the possible arguments in `aes()` depend on which `geom_` or `stat_` you call. For example, `?geom_line` / `?geom_path` give:

> geom_path() understands the following aesthetics (required aesthetics are in bold):
>
> - **x**
> - **y**
> - alpha
> - colour
> - group
> - linetype
> - size

These functions have a `linetype` argument in `aes()` because they draw lines, but it wouldn't make sense to have a `linetype` arg for `geom_bar` for instance.

Comment: Yes, but would add for completeness that these aesthetics may also come from the stat part of the layer, not just the geom.

Comment: Right, I made a tiny edit, feel free to add more info